# GL version 2.1 with the gpu_shared4 extensions is not supported on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS as guest VM

Tags: virtualbox, python, opengl

I am trying to run a python (3.6.9) [script](https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/blob/16f2bfeac7fa24fbefa1b7b56dbe8b3f23f6fc79/Examples/Rendering/Python/Cylinder.py) with VTK 7.1.1 on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS as guest VM using virtual box(6.1 on Win10). But I am receiving the following error:

```
In /build/vtk7‑w4DzBd/vtk7.1.1+dfsg1/Rendering/OpenGL2/vtkOpenGLRenderWindow.cxx, line 640
vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow (0x2a56080): GL version 2.1 with the gpu_shader4 extension is not supported 
by your graphics driver but is required for the new OpenGL rendering backend. Please update your 
OpenGL driver. If you are using Mesa please make sure you have version 10.6.5 or later and make sure 
your driver in Mesa supports OpenGL 3.2.
```

When I run the command

```
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
```

it returns:

```
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 20.0.0-devel - padoka PPA
```

If I understand corretly the visualization on Ubuntu is done by Mesa 20.0.0-devel (required is 10.6.5 - this is OK) but the installed Mesa uses OpenGL 2.1 and not newer (required 3.2 - this is not OK). I have already installed the latest version of Mesa. Any suggestion how to solve this?

---

```
$ apt-cache policy mesa-utils
mesa-utils: 
Installed: 8.4.0-1
Candidate: 8.4.0-1
Version table:
 *** 8.4.0-1 500 
500 si.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages 
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: This seems to be a question about VM video. What do you currently have in Machine Settings → Display → Screen, Graphics Controller?

Comment: Graphics Controller = VMSVGA. I find this situation unclear to me. As I have on this Ubuntu 18.04 also Salome-Meca that also uses VTK for 3D visualization and works OK - but I did not check which version of VTK Salome-Mesa uses.

Comment: Sometimes overriding Mesa version with `MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=3.2 command` helps. Not sure for current case. On my Vbox 6.1 with default Mesa from official repositories the Cylinder is shown normally with the same `VMSVGA` driver. I would recommend to purge *padoka PPA* and retry.

Comment: Where must this command 'MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=3.2' be run? In .py file or in terminal? I will purge padoka PPA and retry and post the end result.

Comment: `export MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=3.2; python3 Cylinder.py` .

Comment: @N0rbert I have purged PPA and now I have: ```OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 21.1.1 - kisak-mesa PPA```. Is this OK?
When I run the suggested command the VTK window opens but it raisesdifferent error: ```[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
python3: ../../src/xcb_io.c:259: poll_for_event: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)``` Any ideas?

Comment: No, it is another PPA. Please add the output of `apt-cache policy mesa-utils; grep -r "^deb.*kisak" /etc/apt --include=*.list` .

Comment: @N0rbert, the output as requested:

mesa-utils:

  Installed: 8.4.0-1

  Candidate: 8.4.0-1
  Version table:
 *** 8.4.0-1 500
        500 http://si.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: And do you have any output for `grep -r "^deb.*kisak" /etc/apt --include=*.list` ?

Comment: It does not return anything. Am I missing something?

Comment: Your `glxinfo` output contains *kisak-mesa* which means its origin from PPA. Please run the following commands to revert packages to their official versions: `sudo apt install ppa-purge; sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa ; sudo ppa-purge ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa`. Then reboot VM and rerun cylinder example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124843/discussion-between-n0rbert-and-lskrinjar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real solution it to disable 3D acceleration in the VirtualBox machine settings.